Magento2.4.6: How to apply category filter on catalog search results product collection?
I want to exclude specific category products from the search results collection, for example, if a customer is not logged in I don't want to show products in search results whose category id is 35.
Any idea?


We have to change in code in case of search product - We have to change the search functionality . means when search product happened then collect the product data without category 35, Means by code we can add this functionality

Use have to write Plugin file like
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class ProductCollectionPlugin
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function beforeLoad(ProductCollection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            // Change the category ID you want to exclude
            $excludedCategoryId = 35;

            // Exclude products from the specified category
            $subject->addCategoriesFilter(['nin' => $excludedCategoryId]);
        }

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
}

Its an idea to prevent that category if you want to hide products you will have to change the collection

what if a product is assigned to multiple categories, like category 35 and 40, in this case it should display in search results
